# Android - Going back to a specific activity via Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP by keeping state

Tags: android, android-intent, android-lifecycle

Let's say I have 4 activities, A, B, C and D. With a button on each of them, A starts B, B starts C, and C starts D. And let's say on activity B, there is a dynamic listview, populated with the information provided by activity A. When I choose an item from B, it starts C, and when I press the "back" button, I see the activity B with the state I left it (dynamic items and scrolling state).

Now what I want is, with a button on activity D, I want to go back to B, by keeping its state (the items data and scroll position), as if I was on C and pressed back button.

So far what I found is, that for my intent to go back to B from D, I should use "FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP" as the intent flag.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could in Activity C start D by startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode). When D ends with specified result in activity C in onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) just call finish(); to finish activity C.
Remember to set result for activity D, when you want to go back to activity B by

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, myIntent); //or any other result or intent
```

Comment: I thought about something like this, but in the real case, between B and D, I have more than one activity. I guess I can apply your solution to all the activities between B and D, but I am curious to know if there is another, a shorter way to do this.

Comment: If you have more activities between I don't think it's a good solution. You could try add flag to intent like FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT or FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY. Good luck.

Comment: I did like you said, for all my activities between, and it worked for me. I was afraid the between activities would be visible before finishing, but it is quite fast and it is like moving one activity to another, you don't really see the between activities. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

add code this way on Button C  click event in Activity C

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(CActivity.this,DActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
 CActivity.this.finish();
```

Comment: But with this code, the user won't be able to go back to C from D with back button, right? I would like to keep this feature.